# Retrieving more than 150 Instagram comments

Tags: instagram-api

## The Problem

I would like to be able view all of the comments on any given piece of [Instagram](http://instagram.com) media, even if the media has over 150 comments. As of now, it is seemingly impossible to view more than the most recent 20 comments on a piece of media on the Instagram site and if one uses either the [Instagram API Console](http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/) or the [Instagram API Libraries](http://instagram.com/developer/libraries/), the most recent 150 comments are returned with no options for pagination or viewing addition comments.

## What I Have Tried

I first, of course, tried the documented [media comment query](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/#get_media_comments) in both the provided console and in my own environment. In both cases, a maximum of 150 comments were returned. Stumped, I began looking for more information online.

Having read over the [Instagram API Documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/) thoroughly, tested various endpoints in the [Instagram API Console](http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/), and read various StackOverflow questions in the Instagram tag and [Instagram API Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/instagram-api-developers) questions on several Instagram topics, I wondered if there was a chance of something being undocumented that I could try.

The [user recent media endpoint](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent_with_client_id) documentation includes parameters for `max_id` and `max_timestamp` that allow for paging through the most recent media for any given user by retrieving the media that comes before said `max_id` or `max_timestamp`. Since each comment comes with `created_time` and `id` attributes, I attempted to add the parameters for `max_id` and `max_timestamp` (both on their own and together) for various comment IDs and timestamps in an attempt to page through comments. None of my attempts worked.

I am now at a standstill unless someone has another suggestion.

## Specific Example

Using the [Instagram API Console](http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/), I took the following steps in attempt to get all of the comments for [this photo](http://instagram.com/p/mv_9OFDTFn).

1. Authenticated myself for an `OAuth2` token
2. Ran a user search query for `coltonlhaynes` to obtain the user `id: 9610843`
3. Ran a user recent media query for user id: `9610843` to obtain the most recent media
4. Gathered information about the most recent media (the above linked photo)

   - media `id: 698057751201132903_9610843`
   - comment `count: 1375`
5. Ran a media comment query for media id: `698057751201132903_9610843` to obtain most recent comments
6. Gathered information about the least recent comment

   - `created time: 1397460230`
   - comment `id: 698269477955776593`
7. Ran a media comment query for media id: `698057751201132903_9610843` with the following additional query parameter strings in attempt to page through comments, but received the same results as step #6

   - `?max_timestamp=1397460230`
   - `?max_id=698269477955776593`
   - `?max_timestamp=1397460230&max_id=698269477955776593`
   - `?max_id=698269477955776593&max_timestamp=1397460230`

## Please Note

To my knowledge, there is no solution to this issue, but since the Instagram Development Team [has stated](http://instagram.com/developer/support/) that they will no longer be monitoring the Google Group and will be monitoring StackOverflow instead, I'm putting this here.

Comment: It's extremely frustrating that their documentation even says that this endpoint gets "[a full list of comments on a media object](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/#get_media_comments)."

Nicely written post. Hope you find an answer.

Comment: its worth saying also that the like endpoint appears to be limited to the 120 most recent likes.

Comment: Now, the endpoint description says: "Get a list of recent comments on a media object. " :) It would have been nice to have pagination atleast for 500 comments. That would have been enough for most uses...

Comment: did you tried using ***InstaSharp*** ?

Comment: ***API Console*** not found https://www.instagram.com/developer/api-console/

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 11):

Ok, This is going to be a very "Hacky" solution, and I am not currently setup to do this myself (due to lack of ADSL at home) but I can provide a step by step guide of how I would approach this issue.

First of all you will need a tool called  ["Charles Web Debuging Proxy"](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)

There is a tutorial on the site on how to enable "SSL debugging" in charles, (which will require you to install a new "root certificate" on your mobile device, to trick it into thinking that https transactions signed by charles are actually signed by instagram.com )

Now Set your mobile device to route all requests through said proxy ( which will have to be installed on your local wi-fi network.)

go to https://www.google.com and check that charles is logging both requests and responses.

Once this is all setup correctly then you can take a look at the API calls which the instagram app itself uses to generate said comment pages.

Answer (score 2):

The generic answer here is "**no, that's not possible** via regular endpoints".

Instagram updated [**Rate Limits**](https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/) (after *Nov 17, 2015*). All rate limits on the Instagram Platform are controlled separately for each access token, and on a sliding 1-hour window. Live apps have higher rate limits than apps in Sandbox Mode.

Which state next limitations in global context:

> #### Global Rate Limits
>
> Global rate limits are applied inclusive of all API calls made by an
> app per access token over the **1-hour sliding window**, regardless of the
> particular endpoint. Rate limits also apply to invalid or malformed
> requests.
>
> - **Sandbox** RATE LIMIT: 500 / hour
> - **Live** RATE LIMIT: 5000 / hour

Plus separately limitations for comments endpoints:

> #### Endpoint-Specific Rate Limits
>
> Endpoints used to publish (POST or DELETE) have rate limits that are applied on an per-endpoint basis.
> Any calls made to these endpoints by your OAuth Client are also
> counted towards the global rate limits noted above.
>
> - **Sandbox**     */media/media-id/**comments***:     30 / hour
> - **Live**    */media/media-id/**comments***:     60 / hour

If your app exceeds any of these rate limits, you will receive a response with an HTTP response code of `429 (Too Many Requests)`.

As soon as Instagram Platform controls it on per `access token` basis, you might achieve a bigger limits using multi-threading with multiple access tokens. But it has caveats: 1. not everything could be paralleled from multiple access tokens, as context will be different. 2. It might contradict with [Platform Policy](https://www.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/) and [TOS](https://www.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't "hacky" at all.

As Instagram gives the link where you are able to get recieve all comments here:
https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/

All you have to do is Looping over the link Instagram is giving you. I've done it like this. Im using the Api to do it this way.

```
  public function getUserMediaComments($id, $limit = 0) {
    return $this->_makeCall('media/'.$id.'/comments', true, array('count' => $limit));
  }
```

The $id is the media_id of the picture. If you foreach over that function with the picture id you'll recieve all comments.

It wasn't that hard when I found out about this way.

You could also do it like this while foreaching over it. :

```
$comments = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/' . 'media/'. $image->id . '/comments?access_token='. $data->access_token));
```

It both returns you an array of the comments of the picture(s).

Comment: No. that's far from a solution. I'm not sure what you're accomplishing. You can't receive all the comments.

You'll need to spoof a request to their GraphQL endpoint to fetch additional comments beyond the 150 limit.

Comment: ***count*** ? not available get 151 - 300 items ?

Answer (score 0):

In accordance to what @Farside said, I don't believe that it is possible to do it by the books. However, you could do it by using Selenium and scraping all the comments in Python. You can use [the InstaPy libary](https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy). They have Quick Start templates to make it really easy.