# Paginating over comments or likes in Instagram API

Tags: instagram, pagination, instagram-api

This question is complementary to [Retrieving more than 150 Instagram comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23069421/retrieving-more-than-150-instagram-comments) and a repetition of [this older post in the group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/instagram-api-developers/likes$20comments$20pagination/instagram-api-developers/76rq1V_ELgg/EI6dXQIqCIQJ).

Currently it appears to be impossible to retrieve a full list of likes or comments for a specific post. There are no documented pagination parameters, and it is unclear how one could paginate over likes as they have no publicly exposed timestamps or time-related identifiers.

At the very least the developer documentation on http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/ and http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/likes/ should be amended to mention that it is not possible to get a full list of either comments or likes.

Are there any workarounds for this, or plans to support pagination for the comments and likes endpoints?

If no such plans exist, how about allowing for control over the ordering of results? This would at least allow for new entries to be retrieved with reasonable confidence.

At the moment, it looks like the /likes endpoint returns results in newest to oldest order, but unfortunately the comments endpoint uses oldest to newest.

Comment: I feel your pain. Just found out about this and I find it very unpleasant to base on their endpoint documentation when developing something, and the final result is stripped. I hope that they will add Pagination to this, but considering that this is already over 1 year old, I somehow doubt it...