# Getting all comments from Instagram Api

Tags: php, comments, instagram, instagram-api

Im trying to fetch all comments from an Instagram picture but i seem only to recieve last 8 pictures. And when I'm trying to var_dump it, it only shows me the last 8 while the count has 14 for instance. When I var_dump other items like pictures there is a pagination. But with comments there aint no pagination. You guys have any idea?

Cheers,

Armando

Comment: The Instagram API does page, [see this section of the documentation](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/#pagination)

Comment: Comments pagination is undocumented, but since the Instagram App is doing it, there is a way. See this answer for getting to the undocumented API endpoint(s) for getting all the comments on a media item: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28137873/325521

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving more than 150 Instagram comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23069421/retrieving-more-than-150-instagram-comments)